# Does not recogize its methods when imported as java.util.* For LinkedList in Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, import, linked-list

I am using java 7 on Ubuntu 14.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

I am writing a very simple code on LinkedList class as:

```
import java.util.*;
public class First
{
    //@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();
        ll.add(5);
        System.out.println(ll);
    }
}
```

My compiler produces an error as:

```
$ javac First.java 

    First.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
            ll.add(5);
              ^
      symbol:   method add(int)
      location: variable ll of type LinkedList
    1 error
```

But same code is perfectly working in Eclipse installed in same Ubuntu. And also working in windows as well.

If I import LinkedList class explicitly in Ubuntu, the code starts to work in ubuntu also:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class First
{
    //@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
          LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();
          ll.add(5);
          System.out.println(ll);
    }
}

$ javac First.java 
Note: First.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
$ java First 
[5]
$
```

In Ubuntu only to use ArrayList class it does not require to implement ArrayList explicitly.

```
import java.util.*;
public class First
{
        //@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList ll = new ArrayList();
        ll.add(5);
        System.out.println(ll);
    }
}

$ javac First.java 
    Note: First.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    $ java First 
    [5]
    $
```

I cannot understand what is the issue.

Comment: Don't use on-demand import statements.

Comment: Do you have a class called `LinkedList` in the same directory as your class `First` ?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Yes you are right. I got it.. This was a silly mistake..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one of your class name `LinkedList` existed in you current directory where `First.java` is saved.

because what i see as a Console error

```
First.java:8: error: cannot find symbol   //method definition not found
            ll.add(5);
              ^
      symbol:   method add(int)
      location: variable ll of type LinkedList
    1 error
```

Here Method definition is not found but `Class LinkedList` definition is found by compiler and in that `LinkedList` Class there is no such method like `add()`.

So, What I guess there must be exist on class named `LinkedList` in your Current directory. So, Compiler picks-up that class as a reference for this line.

```
 LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();
```

but no definition of `add()` method is found .

Thanks